# Headers or library files not found for zlib installando Pillow usando Docker en Windows y Django

Tags: python, django, windows, docker, pillow

Estoy intentando crear un contenedor Docker con una aplicación usando Django. Mi aplicación está prácticamente completa y, ya que usa `ImageField` necesita la librería `Pillow` de Python para funcionar. Para desplegarla sobre AWS he decidido usar Docker para simplificar el proceso, pero `Pillow` no se instala correctamente.

Este es el interior de mi `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

EXPOSE 8000

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc python3-dev musl-dev

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    
RUN python project/manage.py makemigrations

RUN python project/manage.py migrate

CMD [ "python", "project/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Y el contenido del archivo `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
astroid==2.4.2
colorama==0.4.4
Django==3.1.2
isort==5.6.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
PyMySQL==0.10.1
Pillow==8.0.1
pycparser==2.20
pylint==2.6.0
pylint-django==2.3.0
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.1
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Y, en el momento en el que Windows trata de usar la wheel de Pillow, salta este error:

```
#10 97.64   ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
#10 97.64   Running setup.py clean for Pillow
#10 97.85   Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): started
#10 98.87   Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#10 98.87   Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=33317 sha256=2bfe4bde3fbe12405c3fc766ee2e4182f8d3b4253bf57a3e6380da8047b35917
#10 98.87   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b1/c2/ed/d62208260edbd3fa7156545c00ef966f45f2063d0a84f8208a
#10 98.88   Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): started
#10 114.0   Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#10 114.0   Created wheel for typed-ast: filename=typed_ast-1.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=212460 sha256=42a61fedb040ecc46cb317c295e50f874ad5c3109e1dbf32bfc7cff8e90980f8
#10 114.0   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/81/82/a9/ff7c4c54c01d3e1bca029cc8db5f194a0f194625ce9ad6b554
#10 114.0 Successfully built wrapt typed-ast
#10 114.0 Failed to build Pillow
#10 114.1 Installing collected packages: asgiref, lazy-object-proxy, six, wrapt, typed-ast, astroid, colorama, sqlparse, pytz, Django, isort, mccabe, PyMySQL, Pillow, pycparser, toml, pylint, pylint-plugin-utils, pylint-django
#10 116.5     Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
#10 116.9     Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
#10 116.9     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#10 116.9      command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z9y_esqn/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z9y_esqn/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-qro15vkb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
#10 116.9          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z9y_esqn/Pillow/
#10 116.9     Complete output (174 lines):
#10 116.9     running install
#10 116.9     running build
#10 116.9     running build_py
#10 116.9     creating build
#10 116.9     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
#10 116.9     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/PIL
#10 116.9     running egg_info
#10 116.9     writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
#10 116.9     writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
#10 116.9     writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
#10 116.9     reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
#10 116.9     reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
#10 116.9     warning: no files found matching '*.c'
#10 116.9     warning: no files found matching '*.h'
#10 116.9     warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
#10 116.9     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
#10 116.9     no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
#10 116.9     writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
#10 116.9     running build_ext
#10 116.9
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
#10 116.9     a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     Please see the install instructions at:
#10 116.9        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     Traceback (most recent call last):
#10 116.9       File "/tmp/pip-install-z9y_esqn/Pillow/setup.py", line 901, in <module>
#10 116.9         zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
#10 116.9         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
#10 116.9         dist.run_commands()
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
#10 116.9         self.run_command(cmd)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
#10 116.9         cmd_obj.run()
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
#10 116.9         return orig.install.run(self)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
#10 116.9         self.run_command('build')
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#10 116.9         self.distribution.run_command(command)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
#10 116.9         cmd_obj.run()
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
#10 116.9         self.run_command(cmd_name)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#10 116.9         self.distribution.run_command(command)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
#10 116.9         cmd_obj.run()
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
#10 116.9         _build_ext.run(self)
#10 116.9       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
#10 116.9         self.build_extensions()
#10 116.9       File "/tmp/pip-install-z9y_esqn/Pillow/setup.py", line 698, in build_extensions
#10 116.9         raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
#10 116.9     __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     Traceback (most recent call last):
#10 116.9       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#10 116.9       File "/tmp/pip-install-z9y_esqn/Pillow/setup.py", line 914, in <module>
#10 116.9         raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
#10 116.9     __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
#10 116.9     a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
#10 116.9
#10 116.9     Please see the install instructions at:
#10 116.9        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

He probado distintas soluciones:

- Actualizar pip
- Forzar reinstalación pip
- Utilizar versiones anteriores de Pillow
- Utilizar `easy_install Pillow`

Ninguna solución me ha servido.
¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Has seguido [estos pasos](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-on-windows-using-msys2-mingw)?

Answer (score 3):

Ya he encontrado una solución. Resulta que hay que añadir las dependencias manualmente agregando unas líneas al Dockerfile y despues instalar Pillow tal que así:

```
RUN apk add --virtual build-deps --no-cache gcc python3-dev musl-dev zlib-dev postgresql-dev jpeg-dev

RUN apk add postgresql zlib jpeg

RUN pip install psycopg2 Pillow==8.0.1
```

De esta manera el error desaparece. Muchas gracias!